# How to limit duration limit recording and quality of a video with Appcelerator

Tags: android, android-intent, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am making an application that allow users to post their videos. I just want to limit the duration and the quality of the videos.

In iOS, no problem with different options.

For Android, I use intent to launch camera. I saw that we have to possibility to set duration with (it's an example from android developer guide) :

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 8);
```

I tried to do this, from different ways but impossible.

Here is a part of my code :

```
        var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({ action: 'android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE' });
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY",0);
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT",10);
        $.upload.activity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) {
```

Does anyone has an idea how to do this, it's really annoying.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `android.intent.extra.durationLimit` instead, as that is the [listed as value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT) for the `android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT` constant.

Comment: I've just found it too. Quality works but duration limit not. I'm on a One plus One.

this is the code :

`intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.videoQuality",0);
   intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit",10);`