# Set video time limit using intent

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a program where I click on a button and it opens the phone gallery , like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit",60);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

I tried to use this line of code but it doesn't work , maybe this line only works for when the we record with the camera and in my case I want to be able to pick a video from gallery with 60s long or less:

```
i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit",60);
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit duration limit recording and quality of a video with Appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224075/how-to-limit-duration-limit-recording-and-quality-of-a-video-with-appcelerator). As you can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36279069) you need to set `android.intent.extra.durationLimit` as value of `android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT`

Comment: That code is what I have already and it doesn't work

Comment: You're right. In the [cited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36279069), OP even replies _Quality works but duration limit not._